# Last break in switch unnecessary?

Tags: c, switch-statement, default

I was musing over a switch statement I had written for 4 mutually exclusive cases. I inserted a break statement at the end of each case, because I didn't want to do the test again after one case or another had been successful.

Here's the question, though. What, if anything, does the last break do? If the test case 43 succeeds, the break terminates the case, but if there's no break, the default shouldn't run, and so there's no wasted test anyway.

Here's the code:

```
switch(telemetry) {
    case(40):
        printf("\nHouse Telemetry #%i \n", psc);
        break;
    case(41):
        printf("\nNav Telemetry #%i \n", psc);
        break;
    case(42):
        printf("\nDownhill Telemetry #%i \n", psc);
        break;
    case(43):
        printf("\nRealTime Telemetry #%i \n", psc);
        break; // what do I do?
    default:
        printf("\nCommand ID not recognized\n");
}
```

Perhaps one of you compiler gurus can advise me.

Comment: Break statement is not necessary for default, if there are no statements after that.

Comment: The `break` isn't about whether or not you redo the *test* (it is never redone), it is about whether you fall through into the next case.

Comment: It is a good habit to always add `break`. Finding runtime errors with missing breaks are a pain (grandfather-advice)

Answer (score 4):

If you did not have the `break;` in case 43, it would fall through to the default case, and ***also*** execute the `printf("\nCommand ID not recognized\n");`.

Why do you think the `default` would not run?  switch-case will continue execution until it encounters a `break` statement, and this includes the `default` section.

The break therefore ***is*** required for the desired behavior.

---

Putting a `break;` on the very last element of a switch-case (whether it is `default` or `case`) is optional, as it would stop execution that is coming to an end anyway.

I've encountered programmers who feel both ways about it:  That there should not be an extra `break` at the very end of the block because it is not necessary,   or that there should be one for consistency, and on the possibility that the sections get re-arranged in the future.

Comment: I thank all of the respondents. Clearly, I have held an erroneous idea of the inner workings of the switch statement for many years. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` statement is not a language construction that divides codes into separate cases. It is a computed “go to” statement: Based on the switch expression, it causes program control to jump to one of the labels.

Once that jump is completed, the `switch` does not exercise any further control over execution. It does not separate cases from one another or insert jumps or returns at the end of each case. Therefore, if you want control to leave the code for one case and not flow into the following code for another case, you must insert a `break` or other instruction that affects program control (such as `return`).

This characteristic of `switch` statements makes possible uses such as:

```
switch (letter)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        printf("Vowel.\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Consonant.\n");
        break;
}
```

Observe there are five `case` labels using one section of code. If the `switch` automatically separated them, the first four would be empty; nothing would be done for them when `letter` was `a`, `e`, `i`, or `o`.

Another example is where one case does some preparation work and then falls into another case, such as:

```
switch (operation)
{
    case Subtract:
        b = -b;
    case Add:
        result = a+b;
        break;
    case Multiply:
        result = a*b;
        break;
}
```

Here the `Add` case adds two numbers, and the `Subtract` case works by negating `b` and then continuing into the code for the `Add` case. This could not work if the `switch` automatically separated cases. (This is a simplified example, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

The break keyword in each case indicates the end of a particular case. If we do not put the break in each case then even though the specific case is executed, the switch in C will continue to execute all the cases until the end is reached. This should not happen; hence we always have to put break keyword in each case. Break will terminate the case once it is executed and the control will fall out of the switch.